# Helping the SQL server 2014 query optimizer when inner joining with a view column mapped on a function

Tags: sql-server, view, query-optimization, user-defined-functions

Consider a Table named TableA and a View named ViewB.
ViewB contains a column named SomeColumn that is plugged to a scalar function.

This query runs for more than 5 minutes :

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM        TableA
INNER JOIN  ViewB ON
            TableA.Id = ViewB.SomeColumn
```

ViewB.SomeColumn is defined as `dbo.SomeFunction(ViewB.Id, 'abc')`

Here is the first execution plan :
[image: Slow execution plan]

This query runs in less than a second :

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM        TableA
INNER JOIN  ViewB
            TableA.Id = dbo.SomeFunction(ViewB.Id, 'abc') --This is strictly equivalent to /*ViewB.SomeColumn*/
```

Here is the second execution plan :
[image: Fast execution plan]

Why there is such a difference between the two execution plans ?
How could I improve first query performance ?

Comment: If you would add an index on tablea.id I assume it will be faster

Comment: Point a mouse cursor over `scan` icons and review "Actual number of execution" counter.

Comment: you sure it's not cached?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, I only have "Estimated number of execution" which are set to 1 for `scan`. Nevertheless the same property in `Table spool` for the second (slow) execution plan is set to 23536

Comment: Is it possible to make the view into a materialized view?

Comment: You should review **actual** execution plan (button is near _estimated plan_ on toolbar).

Comment: The main difference is in the join operator: slow plan - Nested loops (23536 loop runs), fast plan - Hash join (scan both indexes once, build hash, physical join made at one step). That does not mean HASH join is always better.